# Crawling STS protected sites using Open Search Server

Tags: search, open-source, search-engine

I have configured [Open Search Server](http://www.open-search-server.com/) and it is working fine for all open sites. But I am not able to crawl protected sites that uses [Security Token Service (STS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Token_Service) for authentication. I have specified all authentication parameters(Pattern, Username & Password) for web crawler but it is not crawling.

How can I crawl STS protected web sites using Open Search Server web crawler?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication module of OpenSearchServer supports the following protocols:

- Basic HTTP authentication
- Digest HTTP authentication
- Kerberos

Additionnal implementations can to be developed. As open source software, you can contribute by doing it or ask the help of the community on the [OpenSearchServer SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/p/opensearchserve/).